# EPPlus Excel Export - All data values going into Column A for each record?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, export-to-excel, epplus

I am attempting to add Excel Export functionality to my MVC5/Code-First Entity Framework application via the [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/) library and `System.Linq.Dynamic`. On my Export `View` I have filled a `MultiSelectList` with each of my `INV_Assets` model properties. These then get passed into my `ExportController` to designate which fields of the model are to be exported.

I've gotten the Headers to export into Row 1, but I'm still having difficulty getting the data to export. Currently the data for my selected fields all comes across, but each value is exported as a long string into it's own row in Column A. For example, if I select the following fields (Status, ip_address, mac_address, note, owner, cost, po_number, and description) I get the following:

Row1: `[Status][ip_address][mac_address][note][owner][cost][po_number][description]`

Row2: `[{Status=SIGNEDOUT, ip_address=10.10.121.25, mac_address=10.10.134.11, note=, owner=John Smith, cost=35.00, po_number=G348, description=This is a description of the item.}][][][][][][][]`

Does anyone know how to break this up to where the values actually go into the correct column cells instead of as one long giant string?

**Code below:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using InventoryTracker.DAL;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using InventoryTracker.Models;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;


namespace InventoryTracker.Controllers
{
    public class ExportController : Controller
    {
        InventoryTrackerContext _db = new InventoryTrackerContext();
        public static List<DynamicColumns> DynamicColumnsCollection = new List<DynamicColumns>();

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportUsingEPPlus(ExportAssetsViewModel model)
        {
            ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
            var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestExport");

            var exportFields = new List<string>();
            foreach (var selectedField in model.SelectedFields)
            {
                // Adds selected fields to [exportFields] List<string>
                exportFields.Add(model.ListOfExportFields.First(s => s.Key == selectedField).Value);
            }

            IQueryable selectStatement = DynamicSelectionColumns(exportFields);

            // Loops to insert column headings into Row 1 of Excel
            for (int i = 0; i < exportFields.Count(); i++)
            {
                ws.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = exportFields[i].ToString();
            }

            // Insert Data -- Currently all one long string in Column A per record
            if (selectStatement.Count() > 0)
            {
                ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(selectStatement.Cast<object>(), true);
            }

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            package.SaveAs(memoryStream);

            string fileName = "Exported-InventoryAssets-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
            string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return File(memoryStream, contentType, fileName);
        }

        public IQueryable DynamicSelectionColumns(List<string> fieldsForExport)
        {
            using (var db = new InventoryTrackerContext())
            {
                string fieldIds = "," + "4,5,3,2,6,17,11,12" + ",";

                var taskColum = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumTasks)).Cast<EnumTasks>().Where(e => fieldIds.Contains("," + ((int)e).ToString() + ",")).Select(e => e.ToString().Replace("_", ""));

                string select = "new (  " + string.Join(", ", fieldsForExport) + ")";

                return db.INV_Assets.ToList().Select(t => new DynamicColumns()
                {
                    Id = t.Id,
                    Manufacturer = Convert.ToString(t.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description),
                    Type = t.Type.type_description,
                    Location = t.Location.location_room,
                    Vendor = t.Vendor.vendor_name,
                    Status = t.Status.status_description,
                    ip_address = t.ip_address,
                    mac_address = t.mac_address,
                    note = t.note,
                    owner = t.owner,
                    //Module = t.Module != null ? t.Module.Name : "", 
                    cost = t.cost,
                    po_number = t.po_number,
                    description = t.description,
                    invoice_number = t.invoice_number,
                    serial_number = t.serial_number,
                    asset_tag_number = t.asset_tag_number,
                    acquired_date = t.acquired_date,
                    disposed_date = t.disposed_date,
                    verified_date = t.verified_date,
                    created_date = t.created_date,
                    created_by = t.created_by,
                    modified_date = t.modified_date,
                    modified_by = t.modified_by
                }).ToList().AsQueryable().Select(select);
            }
        }
    }

    public class DynamicColumns : INV_Assets
    {
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Vendor { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string ip_address { get; set; }
        public string mac_address { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public int invoice_number { get; set; }
        public string serial_number { get; set; }
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? verified_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
        public string created_by { get; set; }
        public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }
        public string modified_by { get; set; }
    }

    public enum EnumTasks
    {
        Model = 1,
        Manufacturer = 2,
        Type = 3,
        Location = 4,
        Vendor = 5,
        Status = 6,
        ip_address = 7,
        mac_address = 8,
        note = 9,
        owner = 10,
        cost = 11,
        po_number = 12,
        description = 13,
        invoice_number = 14,
        serial_number = 15,
        asset_tag_number = 16,
        acquired_date = 17,
        disposed_date = 18,
        verified_date = 19,
        created_date = 20,
        created_by = 21,
        modified_date = 22,
        modified_by = 23
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

Thanks to João Silva's suggestion, the fields now come across into their own individual cells within proper selected columns:

**Code**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExportUsingEPPlus(ExportAssetsViewModel model)
    {
        ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestExport");

        var exportFields = new List<string>();
        foreach (var selectedField in model.SelectedFields)
        {
            // Adds selected fields to [exportFields] List<string>
            exportFields.Add(model.ListOfExportFields.First(s => s.Key == selectedField).Value);
        }

       {
            ws.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = exportFields[i].ToString();
        }

        var membersToShow = typeof(INV_Assets).GetMembers().Where(p => exportFields.Contains(p.Name)).ToArray();

        ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(_db.INV_Assets.ToList(), false, TableStyles.None, BindingFlags.Default, membersToShow);

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(memoryStream);

        string fileName = "Exported-InventoryAssets-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return File(memoryStream, contentType, fileName);
    }
```

**Output**:

[image: Excel Output]

The only issue I still have is the `ForeignKey` fields within my model. For example, `[Status]` is defined in my `INV_Assets` Model as:

```
    [Required]
    public int Status_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
    public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }
```

When the current export executes though, instead of getting say `AVAILABLE`/`RECYCLED`, the `[Status]` column in excel contains `InventoryTracker.Models.INV_Statuses` in every cell for each record exported.

Can anyone offer insight into how to get not only the direct `INV_Assets` fields exported, but the `ForeignKey` values for `Model, Location, Status, Vendor, Manufacturer, and Type` also into Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer Founrd Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988951/export-to-excel-linq-include-foreignkey-values-in-tolist)

Added a `ToString()` override on each of my desired Models to ensure the value came through instead of just the object type:

```
public class INV_Models
{

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.model_description;
    }
}

public class INV_Manufacturers
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.manufacturer_description;
    }
}

public class INV_Locations
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.location_dept + "|" + this.location_room;
    }
}

public class INV_Vendors
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.vendor_name;
    }
}

public class INV_Types
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.type_description;
    }
}

public class INV_Statuses
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.status_description;
    }
}
```

**ExportController**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExportUsingEPPlus(ExportAssetsViewModel model)
    {
        ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestExport");

        var exportFields = new List<string>();
        foreach (var selectedField in model.SelectedFields)
        {
            // Adds selected fields to [exportFields] List<string>
            exportFields.Add(model.ListOfExportFields.First(s => s.Key == selectedField).Value);
        }

        // Loops to insert column headings into Row 1 of Excel
        for (int i = 0; i < exportFields.Count(); i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = exportFields[i].ToString();
        }

        var membersToShow = typeof(INV_Assets).GetMembers().Where(p => exportFields.Contains(p.Name)).ToArray();

        ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(_db.INV_Assets.ToList(), false, TableStyles.None, BindingFlags.Default, membersToShow);



        var membersToShow = typeof(INV_Assets).GetMembers().Where(p => exportFields.Contains(p.Name)).ToArray();

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(memoryStream);

        string fileName = "Exported-InventoryAssets-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return File(memoryStream, contentType, fileName);
    }
```

And the output Excel file:

[image: Excel3]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the DynamicQuery. You can specify into `LoadFromCollection` the fields you want to show.
I didn't get to compile this (because it's your code) but It worked on my machine with fake data.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.IO;
    using InventoryTracker.DAL;
    using OfficeOpenXml;
    using InventoryTracker.Models;
    using System.Reflection;
    using OfficeOpenXml.Table;


    namespace InventoryTracker.Controllers
    {
        public class ExportController : Controller
        {
            private InventoryTrackerContext _db = new InventoryTrackerContext();

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ExportUsingEPPlus(ExportAssetsViewModel model)
            {
                //FileInfo newExcelFile = new FileInfo(output);
                ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
                var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestExport");

                var exportFields = new List<string>();
                foreach (var selectedField in model.SelectedFields)
                {
                    // Adds selected fields to [exportFields] List<string>
                    exportFields.Add(model.ListOfExportFields.First(s => s.Key == selectedField).Value);
                }

                // Loops to insert column headings into Row 1 of Excel
                for (int i = 0; i < exportFields.Count(); i++)
                {
                    ws.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = exportFields[i].ToString();
                }

                var membersToShow = typeof(INV_Asset).GetMembers()
                    .Where(p => exportFields.Contains(p.Name))
                    .ToArray();

                ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(_db.INV_Assets.ToList(), false, TableStyles.None, BindingFlags.Default, membersToShow);


                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                package.SaveAs(memoryStream);

                string fileName = "Exported-InventoryAssets-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
                string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                return File(memoryStream, contentType, fileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @João! That made a lot more progress. Now all the fields export into their proper individual cells within the correct column that was selected. The only issue remaining seems to be my `ForeignKey` fields in my Model/Table. Ex: In my `INV_Assets` Model, `[Status]` field is defined as  `[Required]
        public int Status_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }`, but in export `[Status]` comes across in the Excel cell as `InventoryTracker.Models.INV_Statuses` instead of, say, `AVAILABLE`/`RECYCLED`. Thoughts on this?

Comment: I added image of the output above in my EDIT.

Comment: If you need to transform your results. you'll need to project the results of your INV_Asset to another class that has the values ready to be printed. But I really think that outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following?