# Export to Excel - LINQ - Include ForeignKey values in .ToList()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, export-to-excel, epplus

I am attempting to add Excel Export functionality to my MVC5/Code-First Entity Framework application via the [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/) library. On my Export `View` I have filled a `MultiSelectList` with each of my `INV_Assets` model properties. These then get passed into my `ExportController` to designate which fields of the model are to be exported.

I've gotten the Headers (via the `MultiSelectList`) to load into Row1 of Excel and the data from my `INV_Assets` model to export to excel via EPPlus `LoadFromCollection()` as below (example):

**Code**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExportUsingEPPlus(ExportAssetsViewModel model)
    {
        ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestExport");

        var exportFields = new List<string>();
        foreach (var selectedField in model.SelectedFields)
        {
            // Adds selected fields to [exportFields] List<string>
            exportFields.Add(model.ListOfExportFields.First(s => s.Key == selectedField).Value);
        }

       {
            ws.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = exportFields[i].ToString();
        }

        var membersToShow = typeof(INV_Assets).GetMembers().Where(p => exportFields.Contains(p.Name)).ToArray();

        ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(_db.INV_Assets.ToList(), false, TableStyles.None, BindingFlags.Default, membersToShow);

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(memoryStream);

        string fileName = "Exported-InventoryAssets-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return File(memoryStream, contentType, fileName);
    }
```

**Output**:

[image: Excel Output]

The only issue I still have is the `ForeignKey` fields within my model. For example, `[Status]` is defined in my `INV_Assets` Model as:

```
    [Required]
    public int Status_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
    public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }
```

When the current export executes though, instead of getting say `AVAILABLE`/`RECYCLED`, the `[Status]` column in excel contains `"InventoryTracker.Models.INV_Statuses"` in every cell for each record exported.

Can anyone offer insight into how to get not only the direct `INV_Assets` fields exported, but the `ForeignKey` values for `Model, Location, Status, Vendor, Manufacturer, and Type` also into Excel?

I did some reading and thought the `Include()` method would work, but no luck. (Ex.) `[Type]` still displays `InventoryTracker.Models.INV_Types` in all record cells using the following code:

```
ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(_db.INV_Assets.Include("Model").Include("Manufacturer").Include("Type").Include("Status").Include("Vendor").ToList(), false, TableStyles.None, BindingFlags.Default, membersToShow);
```

---

**EDIT**:

I added `using System.Data.Entity` to my `ExportController` which allowed the following to compile:

```
ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(_db.INV_Assets.Include(m => m.Model.model_description).Include(m => m.Manufacturer.manufacturer_description).Include(m => m.Type.type_description).Include(m => m.Status.status_description).Include(m => m.Vendor.vendor_name).ToList(), false, TableStyles.None, BindingFlags.Default, membersToShow);
```

I thought this would do the trick, but during execution I receive:

```
InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code.

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOPerationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code.

Additional Information: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'InventoryTracker.DAL.INV_Models' does not declare a naviation property with the name 'model_description'.
```

I don't understand why this is flagging in this manner. `INV_Assets` has the relation to `INV_Models` defined thus:

```
    public int Model_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
    public virtual INV_Models Model { get; set; }
```

And INV_Models defined as:

```
public class INV_Models
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Model Description.")]
    public string model_description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string created_by { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }

    public string modified_by { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing incorrect on the `Include()`?

---

**EDIT2**:

Thanks to [Eric J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141172/eric-j)'s suggestion, the issue is solved! Added a `ToString()` override on each of my desired Models to ensure the value came through instead of just the object type:

```
public class INV_Models
{

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.model_description;
    }
}

public class INV_Manufacturers
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.manufacturer_description;
    }
}

public class INV_Locations
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.location_dept + "|" + this.location_room;
    }
}

public class INV_Vendors
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.vendor_name;
    }
}

public class INV_Types
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.type_description;
    }
}

public class INV_Statuses
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.status_description;
    }
}
```

**ExportController**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExportUsingEPPlus(ExportAssetsViewModel model)
    {
        ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestExport");

        var exportFields = new List<string>();
        foreach (var selectedField in model.SelectedFields)
        {
            // Adds selected fields to [exportFields] List<string>
            exportFields.Add(model.ListOfExportFields.First(s => s.Key == selectedField).Value);
        }

        // Loops to insert column headings into Row 1 of Excel
        for (int i = 0; i < exportFields.Count(); i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = exportFields[i].ToString();
        }

        var membersToShow = typeof(INV_Assets).GetMembers().Where(p => exportFields.Contains(p.Name)).ToArray();

        ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(_db.INV_Assets.ToList(), false, TableStyles.None, BindingFlags.Default, membersToShow);



        var membersToShow = typeof(INV_Assets).GetMembers().Where(p => exportFields.Contains(p.Name)).ToArray();

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(memoryStream);

        string fileName = "Exported-InventoryAssets-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx";
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return File(memoryStream, contentType, fileName);
    }
```

And the output Excel file:

[image: Excel3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the current export executes though, instead of getting say AVAILABLE/RECYCLED, the [Status] column in excel contains "InventoryTracker.Models.INV_Statuses" in every cell for each record exported.

That is what you get if System.Object.ToString() is called on an instance of INV_Statuses.

Try overriding ToString() in that class:

```
public class INV_Statuses
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // TODO: Return whatever you would like to have appear in Excel
    }

    // Rest of the class here
}
```