# Use EPPlus to export dynamic query result to Excel

Tags: c#, generics, epplus, dynamic-linq

I have an application where users input a large number of data fields and then wish to produce Excel spreadsheets from custom queries on the data.

For single-table queries, I can return an `IEnumerable<T>` and use the `LoadFromCollection()` method in EPPlus to create the spreadsheet with only the requested columns, eg:

```
List<string> fieldNames = userFieldsParam;

var data = Entities.MainStatements
           .Where(ms => ms.FinancialYear.YearString == finYearParam);
var displayFields = typeof(MainStatements).GetMembers()
                    .Where(st => fieldNames.Contains(st.Name)).ToList();

worksheet.Cells["a2"].LoadFromCollection(data, false, OfficeOpenXm.Table.TableStyles.None, 
                      BindingFlags.Default, displayFields.ToArray());
```

However, as the users' queries span related tables, my query returns a Dynamic Class (not an `IEnumerable<T>`), which doesn't load.

```
var data = Entities.MainStatements
           .Include(RevenueStatements)
           .Include(ExpenditureStatements)
           .Where(ms => ms.FinancialYear.YearString == finYearParam)
           .Select(fieldNamesString);
```

I've tried using the (OP's) solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988951/export-to-excel-linq-include-foreignkey-values-in-tolist), by returning an IEnumerable with all the columns (including `.Include`d table columns), but cannot work out how to get MemberInfo data from related tables.  First I tried including the table name in the requested column list, but GetMembers() didn't add them.

Next I tried to create a `MemberInfo` for each of the individual tables, but when I tried to add table name information to collate them in one list, I found that `MemberInfo` is readonly.

```
foreach (MemberInfo mi in typeof(RevenueStatements).GetMembers().Where(rs => fieldNames.Contains(rs.Name)))
{ 
  mi.Name = "RevenueStatements." + mi.Name;     <-- Property or indexer mi
  displayFields.Add(mi);
}
```

How do I populate an Excel spreadsheet from a multi-table query result with custom columns using EPPlus (or other 3rd party solution)?  Specifically, how do I tell EPPlus which columns to include from the related tables?

Comment: Create a custom class with all the properties and map to that instead of a dynamic class.

Comment: @VDWWD Do you mean a class with all possible query fields as it's properties? Won't the resulting spreadsheet be filled with blanks?   I still don't see how to restrict the EPPlus output to only the columns selected. Can you possibly expand on your comment?

Comment: You have to create a class with all the properties you are fetching in `Entities.MainStatements`. If you have datasets with different columns/tables etc you have to create a class for each scenario.

Comment: The problem is, as described, users select which fields to report on - from a large (350+ fields) set of data - not just MainStatements, but also its related tables (eg RevenueStatements, ExpenditureStatements).  Users may be interested in reporting on a half-dozen fields, or half the total number.

Comment: Does the excel contain 350 columns also?

Comment: If users choose to report on all the fields, yes.  So, for eg user1 may only want to see the Totals, while user2 wants to see detail in the RevenueStatements and check that data matches totals in the MainStatements

Answer (score 0):

Build a DataTable using your results and write to excel using EPPlus method LoadFromDataTable();